# How to cut a date/timestamp String?

Tags: bash, cut, stat

So I am using

```
 TIMESTAMP=$( stat -c "%y" $JARNAME.jar )
 print $TIMESTAMP
```

and its output is something like `2015-04-24 17:23:03.000000000 -0500`

I need only the `2015-04-24 17:23:03` part

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you seem to be using the Linux version of `stat(1)`, I'll assume you also have the GNU `coreutils` version of `date(1)`:

```
TIMESTAMP=$( date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -r "$JARNAME".jar )
```

Answer (score 6):

With `GNU` `stat` you could simply use the *dot modifier*<sup>1</sup> (+ field width) between the introductory `%` and the character that specifies the format e.g. `stat --printf "%.19y" filename`, so in your case:

```
TIMESTAMP=$(stat -c "%.19y" infile)
```

With `BSD/OSX` `stat` you can use the `-f` (*format*) and `-t` (*timefmt*) switches:

```
TIMESTAMP=$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' infile)
```

---

<sup>1

dot: together with a field width, the field is not expanded when the text is longer, the text is truncated instead.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Try this with [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
echo "${TIMESTAMP%.*}"
```

Output:

```
2015-04-24 17:23:03
```

Comment: can it be done without { }? Im using that for parameters from outside the script

Comment: You can use GNU grep: `grep -Po '.*(?=\.)' <<< $TIMESTAMP` or `cut -d . -f 1 <<< $TIMESTAMP` or `awk -F. '{print $1}' <<< $TIMESTAMP` or `IFS=. read a b <<< "$TIMESTAMP"; echo "$a"`.

Answer (score 2):

The `date` format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` used in lcd047s answer can be simplified to just `%F %T`:

```
TIMESTAMP=$( date +'%F %T' -r "$JARNAME".jar )
```

From `man date`:

```
FORMAT controls the output.  Interpreted sequences are:
...  
%F     full date; same as %Y-%m-%d
...  
%T     time; same as %H:%M:%S
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use cut:

```
TIMESTAMP=$( stat -c "%y" $JARNAME.jar | cut -d. -f1 )
print $TIMESTAMP
```